# clearing prompt in unix

Tags: c, unix, command-prompt, text-formatting

With the following code I am erasing the prompt but not clearing the screen. What chould be the reason?

```
   printf("\033[7mHello how are you doing? press 'q' to quit\033[0m");
   fflush(stdout);
   ----
   doing some other stuff
   ----

   printf("\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\
           \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\033[0m");
           fflush(stdout);
```

I am erasing the prompt but the traces of it appear until I type something that long.

Answer (score 1):

`printf("\033[2J");` This would clear the terminal screen.

I see you're using skip character `\b`, are you trying to reset the terminal cursor to the beginning? because that can also be done with this:
`printf("\033[1;1H");`

Answer (score 1):

`\b` only moves the cursor position, it doesn't erase the prompt.

To erase write a space for every backspace.

```
char * hello = "\033[7mHello how are you doing? press 'q' to quit\033[0m" ;
int len = strlen( hello ) ;
for( int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++ )
{
    printf("\b \b");
}
```